# Unable to run Google Cloud PubSub in c#, DLL problems

Tags: c#, nuget, google-cloud-pubsub

I am working on integrating Google Cloud PubSub into my c# project, I used NuGet to install [1.0.0-beta11](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1/1.0.0-beta11/), no errors at all.  When I run my project and when it reaches the code that uses pubsub, I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in 
 Google.Api.Gax.dll

Additional information: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

NuGet did install all the dependencies including Google.Apis.Auth.dll, but it's 1.27.1. I have tried everything I could think of, including grabbing 1.21.0 of that dll and using that, but no success. I have been able to run the [.net sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/pubsub/api) just fine with no error.

Any thoughts? Let me know if you need more info

Comment: It shouldn't be trying to load Google.Apis.Auth 1.21.0 at all... that's a very strange version for it to depend on. Could you tell us more about the project type (target framework etc)? Are you able to reproduce this with a tiny project that basically does nothing beside (say) listing topics? Could you check which version of Google.Api.Gax.dll has actually been deployed?

Comment: @JonSkeet Target framework is 4.5, I'm compiling to a class library. Everything seems to be downloading the correct dependencies from nuget (Google.Api.Gax.dll is v2.0.0). I haven't been able to reproduce on a tiny project yet. The project references, app.config, and packages.config all show Google.Apis.Auth.dll as 1.27.1.  I have no clue where 1.21.0 is coming from...

Comment: What other dependencies do you have? Is one of those bringing in 1.21.0 perhaps?

Comment: @JonSkeet The only dependencies I have are other projects and Google.Cloud.PubSub.v1.dll and all the other DLLs that nuget adds with it.  It seems that google.api.auth.dll 1.27.1 and 1.21.0 are both being required.  I can delete 1.27.1 in the bin/debug folder to get an error looking for 1.27.1 and I can add it back it to get the error looking for 1.21.0.  Any tools/methods you would recommend to figure out what is referencing to the different versions during runtime?

Comment: Your library may not have any other dependencies, but does your *application* have dependencies? Again, really being able to reproduce this is key - can you either start with the full application and remove parts, or start with nothing and add bits until you see the problem? (I'm very keen to work out what's going on here...)

Comment: I'm getting this too, I've downloaded the CloudVision V1 SDK and getting the same problem.  The stack trace seems to suggest the error is in Google.API.Gax.TaskExtensions.WaitWithUnwrappedExceptions

Comment: ERROR: System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab'
   at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.WaitWithUnwrappedExceptions(Task task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)

Comment: @JonSkeet FYI updates above

Comment: @JLo: So are you able to create this from scratch? If you're able to reproduce this in a simple fashion, please give all the details - it's very hard to help when I only know bits and pieces.

Comment: @JonSkeet have uploaded a 7zip here: https://drive.google.com/a/virtusales.com/file/d/0BzjTQhXw8pAMc2R0ZjlnMXVtRFk/view?usp=sharing which contains vb.net code, compiled version with the minimal google DLLs required (as far as I can see) - is this useful?

Comment: Well I don't have access to that file, but after that it probably would. (A C# example would be even better, but hopefully there isn't much actual code here anyway...)

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry I'm an idiot, here we go https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzjTQhXw8pAMc2R0ZjlnMXVtRFk/view?usp=sharing  and yeah, it's only a handful of code - can convert to c# if required though

Comment: p,s, google shows an error for some reason, but the blue DOWNLOAD button still works!

Comment: You've provided the source code but not project file - and it's the project file that will show the dependencies. That's the most important part. (It will also tell us which version of the framework you're targeting, which is very important.) We'll get there eventually...

Comment: Oh... I'm not using Visual Studio, just calling vbc compiler directly with this parameters file: https://pastebin.com/hNLgu18k

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147944/discussion-between-jlo-and-jon-skeet).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I've found the reference to Google.Apis.Auth 1.21.0 - it's in the [`Grpc.Auth`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Grpc.Auth/) NuGet package.

If you just add a reference to the `Grpc.Auth` DLL, you'll get this kind of failure - but if you manage *all* the dependencies via NuGet, I'd expect it to be okay - it should add assembly binding redirects for you.

Without knowing your exact setup, it's quite tricky to say more than that - it could be that your *library* needs assembly binding redirects, but the *application* is in control of them... and in particular, if your application only has a reference to the library DLL, that would cause the problem.

As a workaround, you could either manually add the assembly binding redirects (the exact way of doing that will depend on the application type) or just add a reference to `Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1` in the application as well as the library, at which point NuGet will do all the dependency handling for you.

Comment: @Hammy: Are you able to share any more details of the breakage? If you'd rather email me, please do - my email address is on my profile page. It could be very helpful for us in terms of adding a FAQ entry etc.

Comment: I'm still not sure what caused it in the first place, I haven't been able to reproduce. One possible cause is that I had accidentally installed Google.Apis.PubSub instead of Google.Cloud.PubSub, but then that package doesn't reference Grpc.Auth. And I agree, I do think grpc.auth was part of the cause. The fix ended up being to install then uninstall google.cloud.pubsub via nuget to every project in my solution, even though some of them had never had it installed in the first place. Then I installed it into the project that needed it and it worked.

Comment: Sorry not much help, there's a few more things I can try to reproduce, I'll let you know if I find out anything

Comment: @Hammy: Thanks, please do :)

Comment: Switched computers on this same project and this problem showed up again. I used fusion log and again found that Grpc.Auth was referencing Google.Apis.Auth 1.21.0 whereas my project was referencing 1.27.1. I had a binding redirect setup and for some reason wasn't showing up that in the log that it was redirecting.  Due to some project specific post-build batch files moving things around, it turns out the solution to the problem was that the .config file was not in the same directory as the compiled assembly, which was probably also the solution for the original problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can append the following to your `app.config` file.

```xml
<runtime>
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
    <dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth" publicKeyToken="4b01fa6e34db77ab" culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.21.0.0-1.35.1.0" newVersion="1.35.1.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
  </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old issue but maybe will help someone in the future.
Was stuck with it also, it's indeed the bindingRedirect issue.
In my case it was that the app.config was at the wrong level, just at the project level.

Good luck

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Where else would the app.config be at?

Comment: I had multiple projects, so just try to see if you don't missing the "correct" app.config.