# using Firestore with .net class library

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to connect my .net Framework class library to Google Firestore but so far unsuccessfully. According to the documentation( http://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.Firestore/index.html ), I'm trying to connect via a JSON file

```
        string path = JSON file path";
        Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APLICATION_CREDITIAL", path);
        FirestoreDb db = FirestoreDb.Create("project_ID");
```

but an error pops up:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.Auth, Version=1.21.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

does anyone have experience with this?

Comment: What dependencies are being used by your application? You shouldn't be trying to get version 1.21 of the API

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to run Google Cloud PubSub in c#, DLL problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44771019/unable-to-run-google-cloud-pubsub-in-c-dll-problems)

Comment: I read the mentioned post but the solution was with app.config which the class library does not contain.I installed Google.Cloud.Firestore from NuGet package manager and together it installed a lot of additional dll files. I only use Google.Cloud.Firestore

Comment: If you solved your problem put the answer in the Answer box below, it may help someone else with the same problem.

Comment: I can see a couple issues with the code snippet you shared. For starters, the env variable name should be "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS". Also the double quotes seem to be in the wrong place for the path variable. The error says it was not possible to find the file, so either the path is wrong or the env variable name is incorrect. Are you sure this is the code you are using?